# PHP fails to return wrong radio button value from 0 to 1

Tags: php

```
<td id="page">
                <h2>Add Subject</h2>
                <form action="create_subject.php" method="post">
                    <p>Subject name: <input type="text" name="menu_name" value="" id="menu-name"></p>

                    <p>Position: 
                        <select name="position">

                        <?php 
                        $subject_set = get_all_subject();
                        $subject_count = mysql_num_rows($subject_set);
                        for ($i=1; $i <= $subject_count+1 ; $i++) { 
                            echo "<option value=\"$i\">$i</option>";
                        }

                        ?>

                        </select>
                    </p>

                    <p>Visible: 
                    <input  type="radio" name="visible" value="0" >No 
                     <input type="radio" name="visible" value="1" >Yes
                    </p>

                    <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Add subject" >
                </form>



<?php 

$menu_name = mysql_slash_checker($_POST['menu_name']);
$position = mysql_slash_checker($_POST['position']);
$visible = is_numeric($_POST['visible']);


echo $visible;

?>
```

Whenever I echo the radio button I keep getting the value. rather than getting the value of No when i pass it into the post variable, I keep getting the value of YES. and my information is seen as visible in my database. i do not know what i am doing wrong here. please  anyone have any idea what i should do?

Comment: So your question is to echo the value of $_POST["visible"]?

Comment: try to use if(!isset($_POST['visible'])) $visible = intval($_POST['visible']);

Answer (score 0):

I think you have misunderstood what `is_numeric` does. It simply checks if the value is numeric. `0` and `1` are both numeric.

You should instead check the value itself, e.g.

`$visible = ($_POST['visible'] == 1 ? true : false);`

or possibly

`$visible = (bool) $_POST['visible'];`

If you want a string, try (after the above)

`echo $visible ? 'visible' : 'not visible';`

Comment: This would not work because you are comparing a string and a int

Comment: @LucaJung `==` will automatically convert between the two. If I were to use `===` then it would indeed not work. Please read http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 0):

Hi Its because you are printing result of `is_numeric();`. Which is `0/1` only

Try this

```
$visible = is_numeric($_POST['visible']) ? $_POST['visible'] : '';


echo $visible;
```

or simply

```
echo $_POST['visible'];
```